# Unable to go inside directory on Debian 9

Tags: debian, sudo, cd-command

I am logged in as sudo user on Debian 9. When I do `ls` then it shows me there is a directory called `vars`

If I do `cd /vars` then I get error `bash: cd: /vars: No such file or directory`

If I do `sudo cd /vars` then I get error `sudo: cd: command not found`

How I can go inside that directory because I want to edit a file which is inside `/vars/www` but I am unable to go inside it.

**EDIT1**
Screenshot added
[image]

**EDIT2**
The result of command `ls -l` is given below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 104857600 Feb 28  2005 100mb.test
-rw-r--r-- 1 userali myuser 200000000 Aug 22  2014 200MB.test
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 200000000 Aug 22  2014 200MB.test.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 200000000 Aug 22  2014 200MB.test.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        10686 Jan 10  2018 client.ovpn
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        10916 Jul  6 13:40 mainclient.ovpn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root        24682 Jul  6 13:37 openvpn-install.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   2884191 Dec 21  2017 s_.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  10127189 Dec 15  2017 123___.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root           30 Dec 27  2017 vars
```

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory?

Comment: I have added screenshot please check.

Comment: @FrankMartin please write the output of `pwd` or tell us in which directory you are?Because you are in home directory and you want to access `/vars` directory.

Comment: When I do `pwd` then it prints `/home/myuser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `ls -l` output, `vars` is a regular file, not a directory.  This means that you can not `cd` into it.

If it had been a subdirectory of the current directory, you would have used `cd vars` to go into it.

I think you may possibly refer to `/var/www` and that you may just be confused by the *file* called `vars` that you are seeing, but I'm not 100% certain.

If you mean `/var/www`, then use

```
cd /var/www
```

---

If `vars` had been a directory in the current directory, and if you didn't have permission to enter it, `sudo cd vars` would not have helped as `cd` is a shell built-in (not an external utility) which can't be executed though `sudo` on Linux.

On Unix systems where `cd` is available an external utility, `sudo cd vars` would have entered the directory as root, and then `sudo` would have terminated, leaving you in the directory where you started, as yourself (not root).

Comment: Thanks man this is exactly what happened. I was confusing `vars` with `var`

Answer (score 3):

And it seems that `vars` is not a directory, it can be file or anything so it will give you error `vars is not directory`.

And also you are writing wrong command.From your image it seems that you are in your home directory and inside this directory **suppose** you have a directory `foo`. But your command `cd /foo` will search for `foo` directory inside the root directory, which is not present there.

To change directory to `foo` just write command `cd foo` instead of `cd /foo`.And I am assuming that you have privilege to enter the directory.

Comment: If I do `cd vars` then I get error `-bash: cd: vars: Not a directory`

Comment: @FrankMartin please write output of `ls -l` in the question.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the result.

Comment: And that shows `vars` is a file, not a directory. Why do you believe `vars` is a directory?

Comment: @PhilipKendall In my answer I said *assume* because if it was a directory then also his commands are wrong.